# I am facing an issue with redux and react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have this following code. 
   main.js

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('Main', props);
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch >
          <Route exact path="/" component={LoginComponent}/>
          <Route  path="/signup" component={SignupComponent}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapState = ((state, ownProps) => {
  console.log('state', state);
  console.log('ownProps', ownProps);
  return{
    state,
    ownProps
  }
});

const actionProps = {
  login,
  signup
}
let mainApp = connect(mapState, actionProps)(Main);
export default mainApp;
```

and I have this App.js

```
let store = createStore(AppReducer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my question is why I can't access the actions/reduces from my LoginComponent or SignupComponent through props.

This is the output I am seeing on browser console.

```
state {loginReducer: {…}}
main.component.js:29 ownProps {}
main.component.js:12 Main {state: {…}, ownProps: {…}, login: ƒ, signup: ƒ}
auth.component.js:6 Login {match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
```

Can any one please help me out? How to fix this?

Update: 
I fixed it somehow by using this way:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(routeProps) =>   
              <LoginComponent route={routeProps} store={this.props}/>
            }/>
```

But, I am not sure is this the right way to do it?

Comment: As you are not using `mapDispatchToProps` then you must `dispatch` your actions via `store`. e.x `this.props.store.dispatch` and pass the the action.

Comment: I am using please see the code above carefully "actionProps", The redux store props is not inherited to child components. That is my problem.

Comment: What `props` do you see when you log `this.props`?

Comment: @Basheer Ahmed Kharoti,  I see only route props in auth.component.js, I have posted my code with console log.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `mapDispatchToProps` to access the actions and its reducer. Like that

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {login, signup} from './actions'; // Your action file

...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return bindActionCreators({
     login: login,
     signup: signup,
 }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: @Tuan Tran Duy It did not work. I have tried this already. If you see closer ``const actionProps = {
  login,
  signup
}`` This is exactly the what you mentioned. My question is the redux props are not available in any child components.

Comment: And in each component `LoginComponent `, `SignupComponent` you connected it too?

Comment: @Tuan Tran Duy, It suppose to connect together. Which is why I wrapped all the components in Provider. I don't know why isn't showing redux props in LoginComponent.

Comment: `Provider` wrapper is only make a global `store` which has all `state` and `dispatch`. If you want use it in any component, you must `connect` it.

Comment: I think you should read this https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some action functions exported in actions, it is dead simple

```
import { store } from "reduxRoot/store";
import { login } from "./actions";

store.dispatch(login());
```

Then you can observe updated props within your component decorated with `mapStateToProps`.

It can be considered kind of hacky by some, because does not map dispatch to props at all. I find this way simpler and I did not see any adverse implications. If anyone could suggest why that is required, they are welcome, and i will learn one thing.

UPDATE -- to materialize more details;

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   state: state, // only if you need the whole state in the component. 
   someRelevantPartOfState: state.login.relevant.part
})
```

And do `connect` your `LoginComponent` with the above. In your code, only `Main` component is connected. Trying to be consistent with your code,

```
let loginComponentWithState = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

Alternatively, I would use decorations instead, because it keeps component names as they are.

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I tired, this should trigger the actions but the problem is redux props are not available in child components e.g: LoginComponent. How will you get the updated states?

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan Redux props are accessible, just do `mapStateToProps` for the components. In your case it is the `LoginComponent` for example. See the updated answer for that